# Is there a website that I can test TLS SCSV with?

Tags: tls, firefox

I want to test TLS SCSV on a very old version of firefox with Insecure Version Fallback enabled. However, I can not find any server that uses the insecure fallback.

Comment: If the client does not support TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV (as is in your case) then the server cannot detect insecure fallbacks, i.e. there is no special server support needed to have this disabled. Note that you still need some man in the middle attacker trying to downgrade the connection though.